# Enhanced vegetation index using ENVI 4.7 bandmath

Tags: remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, envi, digital-image-processing, evi

I computed Enhanced Vegetation Index using band math in ENVI 4.7 software. The expression used was:

```
2.5*((float(b1)- float(b2))/(float(b1)+ (6*float(b2)) +(7.5* float(b3))))
BYTSCL(float(b1), min = -1.0, max = 1.0)
```

The output EVI file has values varying from 0 to 255 rather than -1 to +1. Can anyone suggest an edit to the expression or a method.

Answer (score 1):

The `BYTSCL` rescales your output from -1 to 1 -> 0 to 255. Remove that last bit, and you don't have your problem. `BYTSCL` is usually used for minimizing storage and bandwidth requirements associated with displaying data online.

If you want to make sure that you do not have values below -1 and above 1, you can use this function:

```
(float(b1) lt -1)*(-1)+(float(b1) gt -1)*(float(b1) lt 1)*float(b1)+(float(b1) gt 1)
```